# Change /clock rate in ROS 2 Gazebo

Tags: gazebo, ros2

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm trying to change the rate at which `/clock` is being published in ROS 2 gazebo, because 10 Hz is far too slow for my application. I found an article [here](https://github.com/ros-simulation/gazebo_ros_pkgs/wiki/ROS-2-Migration:-ROS-Clocks-and-sim-time) that suggests I can set the parameter `publish_rate` to a number (in Hz as I understand it). The following, however, does not work for setting that parameter from my launch file.

Is this parameter just not exposed for some reason? Anybody have a suggestion for setting this?

```
gazebo = IncludeLaunchDescription(                                                                                                      
    PythonLaunchDescriptionSource([                                                                                                     
        os.path.join(                                                                                                                   
            get_package_share_directory('gazebo_ros'), 'launch'), '/gazebo.launch.py'                                                   
    ]),                                                                                                                                 
    launch_arguments={                                                                                                                  
        'gui': 'true',                                                                                                                  
        'publish_rate': '1000.0',                                                                                                       
    }.items(),                                                                                                                          
)
```

Thanks,

--Hunter

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/390701/change-/clock-rate-in-ros-2-gazebo/) by [allenh1](https://answers.ros.org/users/1086/allenh1/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3055 on 2021-11-11

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You can try as this link shows: [https://github.com/robotlabor-education/robotwiki/wiki/[Simulation][Gazebo]-Gazebo-simulation-in-ROS-2](https://github.com/robotlabor-education/robotwiki/wiki/%5BSimulation%5D%5BGazebo%5D-Gazebo-simulation-in-ROS-2)

Create a file somewhere, for example /config/params.yaml, with the following parameters :

```
gazebo: 
    ros__parameters: 
        publish_rate: 100.0
```

Then modify your launch file some like:

```
config_file_name = 'params.yaml' 

pkg_dir = get_package_share_directory('<your package name>') 

config = os.path.join(pkg_dir, 'config', config_file_name) 

gazebo = ExecuteProcess( 

cmd=['gazebo', '--verbose', world, '-s', 'libgazebo_ros_init.so',  

'-s', 'libgazebo_ros_factory.so', '--pause', '--ros-args', '--params-file', config], 

output='screen', 

)
```

Don't forget to edit CMakeLists.txt.

---

Originally posted by [muronglindong](https://answers.ros.org/users/74440/muronglindong/) with karma: 46 on 2021-11-14

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [allenh1](https://answers.ros.org/users/1086/allenh1/) on 2021-11-14**:
Thanks, I actually patched this upstream.

https://github.com/ros-simulation/gazebo_ros_pkgs/pull/1332